# Django: add `__str__` function in models.py doesn't work

Tags: python, django

I'm following the tutorial linked below to build a Django app.

Here is the content in my models.py

```
from django.db import models
class Word(models.Model):
    word = models.CharField(max_length=100)
def __str__(self):
    return self.word
def __repr__(self):
    return self.word
```

in interactive shell, `Word.objects.all()[0].word` can get the actual content, e.g

```
>>> Word.objects.all()[0].word
'the meaning of the word get'
```

Since I've already add the `__str__` function, the code `Word.objects.all()` is supposed to output something like

```
<QuerySet [<Word: the meaning of the word get>]>
```

However, I just got the same thing as the one before I add `__str__` function.

```
<QuerySet [<Word: Word object (1)>]>
```

I've already restart everything but didn't get what is expected to be. Could someone help me with this?

video: https://youtu.be/eio1wDUHFJE?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9ib4HsrXEYpQnTOTZE1x0uc&t=428

Comment: Did you tried overriding  `__repr__`?

Comment: +1 to what @AbdulNiyasPM wrote.  It's unfortunate, but `__repr__` gets called a lot of times, even when it's not supposed to be.  Let us know if this works.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM Thank you. I'm not sure I understand it correctly. I just tried overriding __repr__ in models.py, as shown in updated OP. Nothing changes.

Comment: try: `print(Word.objects.all()[0])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__str__` magic method is part of the python data model and used to create a nicely printable string representation of the object [(link)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__). Its function inside the django context is specified as follows [(link)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#str):

> The **str**() method is called whenever you call str() on an object. Django uses str(obj) in a number of places. Most notably, to display an object in the Django admin site and as the value inserted into a template when it displays an object. Thus, you should always return a nice, human-readable representation of the model from the **str**() method.

Thus, in your case this should work:

```py
from django.db import models

class Word(models.Model):
    word = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.word
```

Answer (score 1):

> For `__str__(self):` to work the `__str__` function (is a method of the class `Article`), it has to be in the same indentation as the class `Article` itself (align it with a tab)

I found this answer in the comment section of that video